# New Install Ubutu 22.04 Wireless Drops

Tags: wireless, 22.04

My recent load of 22.04 worked well for a day then began to drop frequently. The network I post in the paste drops out within a minute of connecting.  Another one on the same router will run for a while.  What do you suggest?  EDIT:  Dual boot Windows 11.  No issues there.  Restarted router too.
[my wireless-info.txt](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/RQXxczk5ND/)

Comment: Start with `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off && sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` See if it improves by disabling wifi power management

Comment: Thank you. Disabling power management improves things quite a bit.  Now once connected, 5G stays on and allows me to use google drive in apps without interruption.   But I have to log in twice, once as admin to authorize device change and then for real.  Also the 5G networks appear only after manually turning off wife then restarting it, and even then my 'automatically connected' 5G network won't start. This is a dual boot machine and Windows 11 seems to work correctly for all networks. Should I submit a new request or continue with this?  Our work so far HAS FIXED the original complaint.  Tks

Comment: You may want to disable the hybrid shutdown in Windows

Comment: hybrid shutdown disabled - never was enabled.   I'll wait for 24.04 and try that before tuning this setup more.   Thank you!